# Why is jurabib producing too much whitespace?

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

In the following example, between the booktitle and the volume, jurabib is producing too much whitespace:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibatsep}{,}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}

@INCOLLECTION{Lehnswesen,
  author = {Oliver Auge},
  title = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen},
  booktitle = {Hand\-w\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
    pages = {Sp.\,717\,--\,736},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  shorttitle = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Lehnswesen}.

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```

Check the output with the highlighted whitespace:
[image]

Any ideas, how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it inserts a space too much. You can try this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\incolledformat}[5]{%
 \bibBTsep{} %
 \ifjb@edby
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#5\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#4\relax
        \bibatsep{}%
      \else
        \bibatsep{}\space%
      \fi
     \fi
    \else
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
            \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\edbysep{}\fi
            \unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\space\Edbyname{} %
        \else
            \edbysep{}%
            \Edbyname{} %
        \fi
        \begingroup
            #1%
        \endgroup
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#4\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#1\relax\else 
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
          .\space%
        \else
          \bibatsep{} %
        \fi
      \fi
      \Volumename~#4%
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#4\relax\else.\fi % volume empty
    \else
      \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\else
        \ifjbchicago\else.\fi
      \fi
    \fi
 \else 
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
      \begingroup
          #1 % editor
      \endgroup
      \ifx\relax#2\relax\else#2\fi
      \bothaesep%
    \fi
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#4\relax
    \else
     \unskip %<--------------------------------- new
      \ifx\relax#5\relax\space\else,\space\fi% volume and booktitleaddon
      \volumeformat{#4}%
    \fi
 \fi
}
```