# Missing comma when no volume/volumetitle given

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

While adding `INCOLLECTION` I recognized, that jurabib does leave out a comma between the booktitle and the address if the entry has no volume. Please compare the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibatsep}{,}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}

@INCOLLECTION{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit,
  author     = {Gerd Althoff},
  title      = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden. Emotionale Ausdrucksformen in der Politik des Mittelalters},
  booktitle  = {Pathos, Effekt, Gef\"uhl},
  pages      = {S.\,145\,--\,161},
  year       = {2004},
  address    = {Berlin},
  howcited   = {1},
  shorttitle = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden}
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit}.

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```

with a screenshot of the output:
[image]

I am already using the fix by @Ulrike Fischer ([Why is jurabib producing too much whitespace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450988/why-is-jurabib-producing-too-much-whitespace/451002#451002)), I think this is related, but I don't know how to fix `\incolledformat` to print this comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the following redefinition of the original `\incolledformat`. The changed line is marked with `new` and a link to this question.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\incolledformat}[5]{%
 \bibBTsep{} %
 \ifjb@edby
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#5\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#4\relax
        \bibatsep{}%
      \else
        \bibatsep{}\space%
      \fi
     \fi
    \else
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
            \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\edbysep{}\fi
            \unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\space\Edbyname{} %
        \else
            \edbysep{}%
            \Edbyname{} %
        \fi
        \begingroup
            #1%
        \endgroup
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#4\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
          .\space%
        \else
          \bibatsep{} %
        \fi
      \fi
      \Volumename~#4%
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#4\relax\else.\fi % volume empty
    \else
      \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\else
        \ifjbchicago\else.\fi
      \fi
    \fi
 \else
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
      \begingroup
          #1 % editor
      \endgroup
      \ifx\relax#2\relax\else#2\fi
      \bothaesep%
    \fi
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#4\relax
      \unskip\bibatsep{} %<------ new https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520741/35864
    \else
      \ifx\relax#5\relax\space\else,\space\fi% volume and booktitleaddon
      \volumeformat{#4}%
    \fi
 \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Naturally this can be combined with Ulrike's answer to the linked question to

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibatsep}{,}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\incolledformat}[5]{%
 \bibBTsep{} %
 \ifjb@edby
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#5\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#4\relax
        \bibatsep{}%
      \else
        \bibatsep{}\space%
      \fi
     \fi
    \else
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
            \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\edbysep{}\fi
            \unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\space\Edbyname{} %
        \else
            \edbysep{}%
            \Edbyname{} %
        \fi
        \begingroup
            #1%
        \endgroup
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#4\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#1\relax\else 
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
          .\space%
        \else
          \bibatsep{} %
        \fi
      \fi
      \Volumename~#4%
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#4\relax\else.\fi % volume empty
    \else
      \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\else
        \ifjbchicago\else.\fi
      \fi
    \fi
 \else 
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
      \begingroup
          #1 % editor
      \endgroup
      \ifx\relax#2\relax\else#2\fi
      \bothaesep%
    \fi
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#4\relax
      \unskip\bibatsep{} %<------ new https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520741/35864
    \else
     \unskip %<------ new https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450988/35864
      \ifx\relax#5\relax\space\else,\space\fi% volume and booktitleaddon
      \volumeformat{#4}%
    \fi
 \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit,
  author     = {Gerd Althoff},
  title      = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden. Emotionale Ausdrucksformen in der Politik des Mittelalters},
  booktitle  = {Pathos, Effekt, Gef\"uhl},
  pages      = {S.\,145\,--\,161},
  year       = {2004},
  address    = {Berlin},
  howcited   = {1},
  shorttitle = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Lehnswesen,
  author = {Oliver Auge},
  title = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen},
  booktitle = {Hand\-w\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
    pages = {Sp.\,717\,--\,736},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  shorttitle = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit,Lehnswesen}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

[image: Althoff, Gerd: Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden. Emotionale Ausdrucksformen in der Politik des Mittelalters, In Pathos, Effekt, Gefühl, Berlin, 2004, S.145–161]

Comment: Awesome @moewe and thanks for your support once more!