# Comma too much when volumetitle given

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

After applying the fix from @moewe as seen in [Missing comma when no volume/volumetitle given](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520741/missing-comma-when-no-volume-volumetitle-given) for books that have a volumetitle a double comma is printed. Please compare the MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibatsep}{,}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\incolledformat}[5]{%
 \bibBTsep{} %
 \ifjb@edby
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#5\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#4\relax
        \bibatsep{}%
      \else
        \bibatsep{}\space%
      \fi
     \fi
    \else
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
            \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\edbysep{}\fi
            \unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\space\Edbyname{} %
        \else
            \edbysep{}%
            \Edbyname{} %
        \fi
        \begingroup
            #1%
        \endgroup
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#4\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#1\relax\else 
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
          .\space%
        \else
          \bibatsep{} %
        \fi
      \fi
      \Volumename~#4%
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#4\relax\else.\fi % volume empty
    \else
      \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\else
        \ifjbchicago\else.\fi
      \fi
    \fi
 \else 
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
      \begingroup
          #1 % editor
      \endgroup
      \ifx\relax#2\relax\else#2\fi
      \bothaesep%
    \fi
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#4\relax
      \unskip\bibatsep{} %<------ new https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520741/35864
    \else
     \unskip %<------ new https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450988/35864
      \ifx\relax#5\relax\space\else,\space\fi% volume and booktitleaddon
      \volumeformat{#4}%
    \fi
 \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit,
  author     = {Gerd Althoff},
  title      = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden. Emotionale Ausdrucksformen in der Politik des Mittelalters},
  booktitle  = {Pathos, Effekt, Gef\"uhl},
  pages      = {S.\,145\,--\,161},
  year       = {2004},
  address    = {Berlin},
  howcited   = {1},
  shorttitle = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Lehnswesen,
  author = {Oliver Auge},
  title = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen},
  booktitle = {Hand\-w\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
    pages = {Sp.\,717\,--\,736},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  shorttitle = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Huepper_PF,
  author = {Dagmar H\"upper and Elvira Topalovic and Stephan Elspa\ss{}},
  title = {Zur Entstehung und Entwicklung von Paarformeln im Deutschen},
  shorttitle = {Paarformeln},
  booktitle = {Phraseologie in Raum und Zeit},
  editor = {Elisabeth Piirainen and Ilpo Tapani Piirainen},
  year = {2002},
  pages = {S.\,77\,--\,99},
  address = {Baltmannsweiler}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit,Lehnswesen,Huepper_PF}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

with the output:
[image]

What needs to be changed so that there is always one comma, never none and never one too much no matter if there is a volumetitle or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jurabib` adds some punctuation directly via the `.bst` file and some punctuation in its LaTeX-side formatting macros. That can make it tricky to follow how exactly punctuation is produced.

I think I tracked down the different functions and macros for the punctuation here and managed to remove the undesirable double punctuation. But I can't guarantee that I haven't broken anything else (I can guarantee though that I only broke stuff related to my answer to [Missing comma when no volume/volumetitle given](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520741/35864), anything else should be unaffected).

It was necessary to recreate some tests for empty fields in `\incolledformat`, because the `.bst` file would not add a comma to the `booktitle` in very specific circumstances.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibatsep}{,}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\incolledformat}[5]{%
 \bibBTsep{} %
 \ifjb@edby
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#5\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#4\relax
        \bibatsep{}%
      \else
        \bibatsep{}\space%
      \fi
     \fi
    \else
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
            \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\edbysep{}\fi
            \unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\space\Edbyname{} %
        \else
            \edbysep{}%
            \Edbyname{} %
        \fi
        \begingroup
            #1%
        \endgroup
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#4\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#1\relax\else 
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
          .\space%
        \else
          \bibatsep{} %
        \fi
      \fi
      \Volumename~#4%
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#4\relax\else.\fi % volume empty
    \else
      \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\else
        \ifjbchicago\else.\fi
      \fi
    \fi
 \else
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
      \begingroup
          #1 % editor
      \endgroup
      \ifx\relax#2\relax\else#2\fi
      \bothaesep %
    \fi
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#4\relax
      % START https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522721/35864
      \ifx\relax#1\relax
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
          \unskip\bibatsep{} 
        \fi
      \fi  
      %  END  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522721/35864
    \else
     \unskip %<------ new https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450988/35864
      \ifx\relax#5\relax\space\else,\space\fi% volume and booktitleaddon
      \volumeformat{#4}%
    \fi
 \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit,
  author     = {Gerd Althoff},
  title      = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden. Emotionale Ausdrucksformen in der Politik des Mittelalters},
  booktitle  = {Pathos, Effekt, Gef\"uhl},
  pages      = {S.\,145\,--\,161},
  year       = {2004},
  address    = {Berlin},
  howcited   = {1},
  shorttitle = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Lehnswesen,
  author = {Oliver Auge},
  title = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen},
  booktitle = {Hand\-w\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
  pages = {Sp.\,717\,--\,736},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  shorttitle = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Huepper_PF,
  author = {Dagmar H\"upper and Elvira Topalovic and Stephan Elspa\ss{}},
  title = {Zur Entstehung und Entwicklung von Paarformeln im Deutschen},
  shorttitle = {Paarformeln},
  booktitle = {Phraseologie in Raum und Zeit},
  editor = {Elisabeth Piirainen and Ilpo Tapani Piirainen},
  year = {2002},
  pages = {S.\,77\,--\,99},
  address = {Baltmannsweiler}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit,Lehnswesen,Huepper_PF}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

[image: Althoff, Gerd: Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden. Emotionale Ausdrucksformen in der Politik des Mittelalters, In Pathos, Effekt, Gefühl, Berlin, 2004, S.145–161//Auge, Oliver: Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen, In Cordes, Albrecht etal. (Hrsg.): Handwörterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte, Band III, Konfliktbewältigung–Nowgorod, Berlin, 2016, Sp.717–736//Hüpper, Dagmar/Topalovic, Elvira/Elspaß, Stephan: Zur Entstehung und Entwicklung von Paarformeln im Deutschen, In Piirainen, Elisabeth/Piirainen, Ilpo Tapani (Hrsg.): Phraseologie in Raum und Zeit, Baltmannsweiler, 2002, S.77–99]

Comment: Just as a warning to future visitors: As far as I am aware `jurabib` is virtually unmaintained at the moment (it was last updated almost 16 years ago) and has (now) a very small user base. I find `jurabib` fascinating because it played an important role in the evolution of `biblatex` (in my opinion and to my knowledge at least). Furthermore, it can be customised in ways and has features many BibTeX styles can only dream of. ...

Comment: ... But it appears to be a very complex beast. Its structure and the entire code setup make it extremely hard to modify things for which there is no simple interface. Especially the shared responsibility between `.bst` file and LaTeX macros for (light) formatting make things hard to understand. (`biblatex` got more radical there: all formatting is done on the LaTeX side. The BibTeX/Biber side only provides the almost raw data.) Unless `jurabib` appears to give you exactly what you need, you may want to look for an alternative.

Comment: Thanks @moewe, your fix works and it seems in my document it has no negative side effects. However I agree with your comment, jurabib in its current state has to be taken with a grain of salt!

Comment: +1 for the **remarks in the comment** and the **detective work** in the answer.