# Comma omitted again if booktitle ends with a question mark

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

After @moewe gave the last tip for a fix in [Comma too much when volumetitle given](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522721/comma-too-much-when-volumetitle-given/522793) I really thought this is it, however there is a new funny effect of `bibtex` or `jurabib`.

Please compare the new MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibatsep}{,}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\incolledformat}[5]{%
 \bibBTsep{} %
 \ifjb@edby
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#5\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#4\relax
        \bibatsep{}%
      \else
        \bibatsep{}\space%
      \fi
     \fi
    \else
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
            \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\edbysep{}\fi
            \unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\unskip\space\Edbyname{} %
        \else
            \edbysep{}%
            \Edbyname{} %
        \fi
        \begingroup
            #1%
        \endgroup
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#4\relax\else
      \ifx\relax#1\relax\else 
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
          .\space%
        \else
          \bibatsep{} %
        \fi
      \fi
      \Volumename~#4%
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \ifx\relax#4\relax\else.\fi % volume empty
    \else
      \ifjb@humanbst@loaded\else
        \ifjbchicago\else.\fi
      \fi
    \fi
 \else
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
      \begingroup
          #1 % editor
      \endgroup
      \ifx\relax#2\relax\else#2\fi
      \bothaesep %
    \fi
    #3%
    \ifx\relax#4\relax
      % START https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522721/35864
      \ifx\relax#1\relax
        \ifx\relax#5\relax
          \unskip\bibatsep{} 
        \fi
      \fi  
      %  END  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522721/35864
    \else
     \unskip %<------ new https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450988/35864
      \ifx\relax#5\relax\space\else,\space\fi% volume and booktitleaddon
      \volumeformat{#4}%
    \fi
 \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit,
  author     = {Gerd Althoff},
  title      = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden. Emotionale Ausdrucksformen in der Politik des Mittelalters},
  booktitle  = {Pathos, Effekt, Gef\"uhl},
  pages      = {S.\,145\,--\,161},
  year       = {2004},
  address    = {Berlin},
  howcited   = {1},
  shorttitle = {Freiwilligkeit und Konsensfassaden}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Lehnswesen,
  author = {Oliver Auge},
  title = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen},
  booktitle = {Hand\-w\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
    pages = {Sp.\,717\,--\,736},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  shorttitle = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Huepper_PF,
  author = {Dagmar H\"upper and Elvira Topalovic and Stephan Elspa\ss{}},
  title = {Zur Entstehung und Entwicklung von Paarformeln im Deutschen},
  shorttitle = {Paarformeln},
  booktitle = {Phraseologie in Raum und Zeit},
  editor = {Elisabeth Piirainen and Ilpo Tapani Piirainen},
  year = {2002},
  pages = {S.\,77\,--\,99},
  address = {Baltmannsweiler}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Roedel_Kg_Ruprecht,
  howcited = {1},
  author = {Ute R\"odel},
  title = {K\"onig Ruprecht (1400\,--\,1410) als Richter und Schlichter},
  shorttitle = {K\"onig Ruprecht},
  booktitle = {Mit Freundschaft oder mit Recht?},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {S.\,41\,--\,83},
  address = {K\"oln}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Althoff_Freiwilligkeit,Lehnswesen,Huepper_PF,Roedel_Kg_Ruprecht}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]
and you see that if the last character of the booktitle is a question mark, the comma will be omitted again. A simple `booktitle = {Mit Freundschaft oder mit Recht?\relax},` does the trick, however I think bibtex or jurabib should be able to handle a standard character in the booktitle, correct?

Comment: Try to protect it with braces: `booktitle = {{Mit Freundschaft oder mit Recht?}},`

Comment: Hi Sigur, this is what the \relax does as well, so theoretically this issue is solved, but to me this is more a quick fix and it seems under the hood something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behaviour and `jurabib` does quite some work to make sure the comma is suppressed after `.`, `!` and `?`.

In particular `jurabib.bst` contains

```
FUNCTION {check.punct.instead.of.add.period.incoll}
{ duplicate$
  get.final.nonrightbrace.char
  duplicate$ "." = swap$
  duplicate$ "!" = swap$
  "?" = or or
  { "} " * }
  { type$ "incollection" = booktitle empty$ not and volume empty$ and editor empty$ and booktitleaddon empty$ and
        { "} " * }
        { "}\bibatsep {} " * }
    if$
  }
  if$
}
```

Even though I don't exactly know what all involved functions do, it is possible to guess that this piece of code tries to check if the last character in the `booktitle` is `.`, `!` or `?` and that in that case `\bibatsep {}` (which produces the comma) is suppressed.

---

If you don't want this, the best way to remove this feature would be to modify the `.bst` file so that no such test is performed. There are actually three appearances of this test and all of them would have to be removed.

The function just shown would then reduce to

```
FUNCTION {check.punct.instead.of.add.period.incoll}
{  type$ "incollection" = booktitle empty$ not and volume empty$ and editor empty$ and booktitleaddon empty$ and
      { "} " * }
      { "}\bibatsep {} " * }
  if$
}
```

A similar thing would have to happen to the other occurrences of this idiom in `check.punct.instead.of.add.period` and `check.punct.instead.of.add.period.art`.

Because it is tedious to do all the modifications, I have uploaded the modified file to https://gist.github.com/moewew/8dccdc76c6897b38c06b97f046a7943b.

The full `diff` to the original `jurabib.bst` is

```
--- jurabib.bst 2009-03-24 11:00:31.000000000 +0100
+++ jurabib-allowdoublepunctuation.bst  2020-01-06 20:48:06.139082800 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,13 @@
+%%%% `jurabib-allowdoublepunctuation.bst'
+%%%% 2020-01-06 MW
+%%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523082/35864
+%%%% allow comma after `.', `!' and `?'
+%%%% `jurabib.bst' actively suppresses these combinations,
+%%%% this modification removes the code for that
+%%%% changes to
+%%%% check.punct.instead.of.add.period
+%%%% check.punct.instead.of.add.period.art
+%%%% check.punct.instead.of.add.period.incoll
 %%
 %% This is file `jurabib.bst',
 %% generated with the docstrip utility.
@@ -689,59 +699,37 @@


 FUNCTION {check.punct.instead.of.add.period}
-{ duplicate$
-  get.final.nonrightbrace.char
-  duplicate$ "." = swap$
-  duplicate$ "!" = swap$
-  "?" = or or
-  { "} " * }
-  { "}\bibatsep {} " * }
-  if$
+{
+  "}\bibatsep {} " *
 }

 FUNCTION {check.punct.instead.of.add.period.art}
-{ duplicate$
-  get.final.nonrightbrace.char
-  duplicate$ "." = swap$
-  duplicate$ "!" = swap$
-  "?" = or or
+{ pages empty$ note empty$ url empty$ and and
   { "} " * }
-  { pages empty$ note empty$ url empty$ and and
-    { "} " * }
-    { volume empty$
-         { pages empty$
-              { "}\ajtsep {} " * }
-              { crossref missing$
-                    { month empty$
-                         { "}\ajtsep {} " * }
-                         { "}\ajtsep " * }
-                      if$
-                    }
-                    { "}\ajtsep " * }
-                if$
-              }
-          if$
-         }
-         { "}\ajtsep {} " * }
-       if$
-    }
-   if$
+  { volume empty$
+       { pages empty$
+            { "}\ajtsep {} " * }
+            { crossref missing$
+                  { month empty$
+                       { "}\ajtsep {} " * }
+                       { "}\ajtsep " * }
+                    if$
+                  }
+                  { "}\ajtsep " * }
+              if$
+            }
+        if$
+       }
+       { "}\ajtsep {} " * }
+     if$
   }
   if$
 }

 FUNCTION {check.punct.instead.of.add.period.incoll}
-{ duplicate$
-  get.final.nonrightbrace.char
-  duplicate$ "." = swap$
-  duplicate$ "!" = swap$
-  "?" = or or
-  { "} " * }
-  { type$ "incollection" = booktitle empty$ not and volume empty$ and editor empty$ and booktitleaddon empty$ and
-        { "} " * }
-        { "}\bibatsep {} " * }
-    if$
-  }
+{  type$ "incollection" = booktitle empty$ not and volume empty$ and editor empty$ and booktitleaddon empty$ and
+      { "} " * }
+      { "}\bibatsep {} " * }
   if$
 }
```

---

If you don't want to modify the `.bst` file, I guess the quickest way to deal with this is indeed with `\relax` as you suggest in the question.

```
booktitle = {Mit Freundschaft oder mit Recht?\relax},
```

`?` is no longer the last character (modulo braces) in the string, so the tests will yield false and `jurabib` does not detect the `?`.

A similar alternative would be

```
booktitle = {Mit Freundschaft oder mit Recht?{}},
```

Note that it does *not* help to protect the `?` or the entire title with braces (as in `booktitle = {Mit Freundschaft oder mit Recht{?}},` or similar), since `jurabib` strips all right braces before looking at the string.