# Too much whitespace with JuraBiB again

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

After [Why is jurabib producing too much whitespace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450988/why-is-jurabib-producing-too-much-whitespace/451002#451002) was solved I thought there wouldn't be any other issues, but it seems that jurabib has more hidden secretes where it creates whitespaces. Please compare this MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibatsep}{,}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}

@BOOK{URH_6,
  title = {Urkundenregesten zur Tätigkeit des deutschen Königs- und Hofgerichts bis 1451},
  year = {1990},
  editor = {Bernhard Diestelkamp},
  author = {Friedrich Battenberg},
  volume = {6},
  series = {Quellen und Forschungen zur h\"ochsten Gerichtsbarkeit im alten Reich},
  address = {K\"oln},
  howcited = {1},
  shorttitle = {URH~6},
  volumetitle = {Die K\"onigszeit Karls IV. (1346\,--\,1355~M\"arz)}
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{URH_6}.

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```

And this output:
[image]

Which command needs modification here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `\renewcommand\jbedafti[1]{\ignorespaces}`. In your example it works. But I can't garanty that it doesn't remove a wanted space elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for this quick and easy fix, on the first glance it didn’t negatively affect any other entry.

Answer (score 2):

Ulrike Fischer's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520772/35864) is probably easier to implement and an alternative solution would be

```
\renewcommand\jbedafti[1]{\unskip}
```

But if you want to address the root cause of this, you may want to take a look at `jurabib.bst`.

The original `jurabib.bst` produces a `.bbl` file like

```
 \jbbibargs {\bibnf {Battenberg} {Friedrich} {F.} {} {}\jbtiafed {\bibfnfont
  {;} \bibenf {Diestelkamp} {Bernhard} {B.} {} {} \edfont {\editorname}}}
  {Friedrich Battenberg} {au} {sexless} {\bibtfont {Urkundenregesten zur
  Tätigkeit des deutschen Königs- und Hofgerichts bis 1451}\bibatsep {}
  \volumeformat {6} Quellen und Forschungen zur h\"ochsten Gerichtsbarkeit im
  alten Reich\bibatsep {} \jbedafti {\edbyname {} Bernhard Diestelkamp,} Die
  K\"onigszeit Karls IV. (1346\,--\,1355~M\"arz),  \apyformat {K\"oln\bibbdsep
  {} 1990}} {\bibhowcited} \jbdoitem {{Battenberg}{Friedrich}{F.}{}{}}
  {{Diestelkamp}{Bernhard}{B.}{}{}} {} \bibAnnoteFile {URH_6}
```

and in your setting `\jbedafti` simply swallows its single argument so that we end up with two spaces: The one before `\jbedafti` and the one after its argument.

The problematic space can be removed by moving the space after the argument of `jbedafti` into the argument like so

```
  alten Reich\bibatsep {} \jbedafti {\edbyname {} Bernhard Diestelkamp, }Die
```

To do that we need to edit a copy of `jurabib.bst` a bit.

1. Find `jurabib.bst` on your machine (type in `kpsewhich jurabib.bst` on the command line).
2. Copy the file to a place where BibTeX can find it (https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf, the same folder as your document will do just fine) and rename it to `jurabib-sp.bst`.
3. Open `jurabib-sp.bst` and replace the

   ```
     author empty$ not editor empty$ not and
         { "\jbedafti {\edbyname {} " editor * "," * * "} " * }
         'skip$
     if$
   ```

   in ll. 2158-2161 of `FUNCTION {book}` with

   ```
     author empty$ not editor empty$ not and
         { "\jbedafti {\edbyname {} " editor * ", }" * * }
         'skip$
     if$
   ```
4. Add a short notice to the top of the file explaining the change. Include the date of the change and your name.

The diff between `jurabib.bst` and `jurabib-sp.bst` should look roughly like

```
--- jurabib.bst 2019-12-17 22:42:13.765457300 +0100
+++ jurabib-sp.bst  2019-12-17 22:31:40.788162100 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,8 @@
+%%%% jurabib-sp.bst for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520746/35864
+%%%% 2019-12-17 MW
+%%%% small edit to the usage of \jbedafti
+%%%%
+%%%% the original file is distributed under GPL v2
 %%
 %% This is file `jurabib.bst',
 %% generated with the docstrip utility.
@@ -2156,7 +2161,7 @@
     { format.btitle "title" output.check }
   if$
   author empty$ not editor empty$ not and
-      { "\jbedafti {\edbyname {} " editor * "," * * "} " * }
+      { "\jbedafti {\edbyname {} " editor * ", }" * * }
       'skip$
   if$
   make.translators output
```

If you don't want to go through these steps, you can download `jurabib-sp.bst` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/b10236c49c6f574e53910e66cde83e57.

Then use

```
\bibliographystyle{jurabib-sp}
```

instead of `\bibliographystyle{jurabib}` in your document.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibatsep}{,}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{URH_6,
  title = {Urkundenregesten zur Tätigkeit des deutschen Königs- und Hofgerichts bis 1451},
  year = {1990},
  editor = {Bernhard Diestelkamp},
  author = {Friedrich Battenberg},
  volume = {6},
  series = {Quellen und Forschungen zur h\"ochsten Gerichtsbarkeit im alten Reich},
  address = {K\"oln},
  howcited = {1},
  shorttitle = {URH~6},
  volumetitle = {Die K\"onigszeit Karls IV. (1346\,--\,1355~M\"arz)}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{URH_6}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib-sp}
\end{document}
```

[image: Battenberg, Friedrich; Diestelkamp, Bernhard (Hrsg.): Urkundenregesten zur Tätigkeit des deutschen Königs- und Hofgerichts bis 1451, Band 6, Quellen und Forschungen zur höchsten Gerichtsbarkeit im alten Reich, Die Königszeit Karls IV. (1346–1355 März), Köln, 1990]

Comment: Thank you for this thorough and complete answer. I think it actually is the more „correct“ one and would jurabib still be supported it, this should actually be in the distributed file! However I cannot accept two answers and as the other worked too and is simpler to implement, what would be the right way to deal with it on Stackexchange?

Comment: @TobiBS There are basically no rules about which answer to accept: It's entirely up  to you. I think it usually makes sense to accept the answer that you are actually using, but you can also decide to accept another answer instead.